# Implement Binary Exponentiation

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, binary

## Background

In programming, there is a recursive algorithm called [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which allows for large integer powers to be calculated in a faster way. Given a non-zero base \$x\$ and a non-negative exponent \$n\$, the algorithm goes something like this (based on the example code from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Recursive_version)):

```pascal
Function exp_by_squaring(x, n)
    if n = 0  then return  1;
    else if n is even  then return exp_by_squaring(x * x,  n / 2);
    else if n is odd  then return x * exp_by_squaring(x * x, (n - 1) / 2);
```

Basically, the code "reduces" the exponent term by first checking whether the current exponent is odd or even, then if it is even, just square root it; otherwise, divide by the base then square root it. Then repeat until the exponent reaches \$0\$. If the exponent is initially \$0\$, then just return \$1\$ directly.

This allows for an exponent term to be calculated faster than just multiplying the base by itself one at a time.

## Example

Here is an example of the algorithm being applied on \$x=3,n=21\$.

1. \$n=21\$ is odd and non-zero, so we divide by the base, then square root. In this case, the number reduces to \$\sqrt{\frac{3^{21}}3}=3^{10}\$.
2. \$n=10\$ is even and non-zero, so we simply take the square root. \$\sqrt{3^{10}}=3^5\$.
3. \$n=5\$ is odd and non-zero, so we divide by the base, then square root. \$\sqrt{\frac{3^5}3}=3^2\$.
4. Continuing the process, we get \$3^1\$ then \$3^0\$, after which the recursion stops.

## Task

Notice how at each step in the example above, we have a value which resulted from reducing the original number. Your task is to return a list of these numbers, given a non-zero integer base \$x\ne-1\$ and a non-negative integer exponent \$n\$. The list should always contain the initial value as the first element. The list can be returned in reverse order if you want to.

## Test Cases

```
   x, n     -> Output
   3, 21    -> [10460353203, 59049, 243, 9, 3, 1]
1000, 0     -> [1]
   2, 15    -> [32768, 128, 8, 2, 1]
   1, 40000 -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  21, 3     -> [9261, 21, 1]
   2, 30    -> [1073741824, 32768, 128, 8, 2, 1]
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Do we have to return the trailing 1?

Comment: @emanresuA Nah, too many answers, it’s too late to change now.

Comment: can you add some test cases with negatives?

Comment: @tsh will clarify, no -1 exponent

Comment: Wait, didn’t I already say nonnegative exponent

Comment: @steffan on my phone rn so it’s a bit hard to edit the post. I’ll put some test cases like that when I get on my laptop

Comment: @AidenChow Sorry, i massed up them...

Comment: I'm curious why you decided to require the output in backwards order, basically punishing iterative solutions so they can't just do the shift/multiply algorithm and append the temporary at each step to an output buffer.  Was that intentional to make it not "too easy" with a loop?  The way the problem is framed, you're actually requiring roots, not exponentiation at all.

Comment: This would be a big pain to do in asm, I think much more work than an integer power function.  e.g. prepend a 1, then do an efficient binary exponentiation, then reverse the array?  Maybe in C you could use recursion to fill the array from the end, with extra pointer and counter args?  Or I guess print inside the recursion like the existing C answer does.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you read the rules, you can see that "the list can be returned in reverse order if you want to." So you can return it in whatever order (ascending or descending) is golfier to you.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Still the `1` floating around to store separately, but ok.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I can't really change that now, there's too many answers.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that :/

Comment: The 3^21 test-case overflows `uint32_t`; I assume it's fine to use that size or `int`, instead of spending more characters (or machine-code bytes) on wider types?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah that's fine.

Comment: Another relevant test-case: non-trivial with an even exponent.  Entering the loop with `prod=1` and letting the first iteration do `1*1 * x` works for odd exponents, but fails for even exponents because the `* x` doesn't happen until after some iterations.

Comment: @PeterCordes What do you mean non-trivial with an even exponent? You mean something like `2^128`?

Comment: I mean a base other than 1 or 0, and an even exponent other than 0.  e.g. `2^30`

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, I will add that test case after I find my code.

Comment: Ok I've added it.

Comment: BTW, I updated my answer with a footnote with a more normal iterative binary exponentiation implementation, like I was expecting to be able to do before I got into the details and found out it wouldn't generate the right temporaries for the proof-of-work array.  In case you're curious. its temporary array could be an interesting proof-of-work for another version of the question that doesn't allow the same `n/=2` iteration without a check for odd/even (or remainder).  Worth considering sometime to revisit this question, possibly making it more likely to get answers that actually do *binary* exp

Comment: Related challenge: [Implement pow with overflow checking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/249685) - an actual iterative or recursive exponentiation may be able to cheaply add exit-on-overflow at each step.

Answer (score 9):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
‡½⌊↔e
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUCIsIiIsIuKAocK94oyK4oaUZSIsIiIsIjIxLCAzXG4wLCAxMDAwXG4xNSwgMlxuNDAwMDAsIDFcbjMsIDIxIl0=)

Takes inputs in reverse order.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
HḞ$Ƭ*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4Y55KsfWaDn8///fyPC/MQA)

Takes inputs in reverse order.

### Explanation

```
HḞ$Ƭ*@  Dyadic link f(n, x)
   Ƭ    Repeatedly apply on n until the results are no longer unique
  $     Last two links as a monad:
H        Halve
 Ḟ       Floor
    *@  x to the power of each
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
:Ƭ2*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/q2BojLYf///8bGf43BgA)

Takes `n` on the left, and `x` on the right. Based on [Steffan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249464/66833), so be sure to give them an upvote as well.

### How it works

```
:Ƭ2*@ - Main link. Takes n on the left and x on the right
 Ƭ    - Repeatedly apply until a duplicate value is found:
: 2   -   Floor divide n by 2
   *@ - Raise x to each power
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 34 bytes

```
f(x,n)=[x^m\=2|i<-binary(m=2*n+1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN5XSNCp08jRtoyvicmNsjWoybXSTMvMSiyo1cm2NtPK0DTVjoSpDEwsKcio1EhV07RQKijLzSoBMJRBHSSE5MSdHI01HIVFTU0chOtpYx8gwFsgwNDAw0DEAsYx0DE3BIjomQDGIkKGOcWysJsRwmHMA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 29 bytes

```
f(a,n)=if(n,f(a,n\2)*x+a^n,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWe9M0EnXyNG0z0zTydMDsGCNNrQrtxLg8HUNNiJqboYkFBTmVGokKunYKBUWZeSVAphKIo6SQnJiTo5Gmo5CoqamjEB1trGNkGAtkGBoYGOgYgFhGOoamYBEdE6AYRMhQxzg2Fmo4zCEA)

This returns a polynomial whose coefficients are the results.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
bη0šÙCm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6dx2g6MLD890zv3/38iQyxgA)

```
b    convert the exponent to binary
η    takes all prefixes
0š   append the prefix "0", to include 1 in the list
Ù    uniquify, since if the exponent was 0 then "0" was already a prefix
C    convert each prefix from binary to a number
m    exponentiation
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
·.Γ;ï}m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Ha9c5OtD6@vzf3/38iQyxgA)

A port of the Vyxal and Jelly answer

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
x=>g=n=>[x**n,...n?g(n>>1):[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBCoAgEIXhfSeZiRLN2gTaQcJFlEoRY1REt7dahtvv/W8ZruEY93k7SwqTjU7FW2mvSOn@znMqGGPUeSCtBba9MXEMdITVsjV4cCARKoGY/VVwzhFSr15s0hqh/g5J/Q4SMT4)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>66</s> 53 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)*

```
r;f(x,n){printf("%d ",r=n?f(x,n/2),(n%2?x:1)*r*r:1);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9LCoMwEF3HUwyCkGhKE61Qmoo38AIipVhSsmgqUUEQL9ArdNONh-ptOordzDzej5n3XF_udf35zH2nd8dv6pSmA7dsbJyxnaZ-cAOfu8zmK7-PGac2iPPhJFnoQodLTVv49bgaS9noEYxCARmkHIa2rBCNCQcphOAQI8ApJw5202IkUJFoP4jVlEzKI_rp6NJkMqHAnAsFUWSWeoK3tKWp1gZTMfSSpu9a6vsLnrztov9bPw)

Comment: [53 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9LCoMwEF3HUwyCkGhKE61Qmoo38AIipVhSsmgqUUEQL9ArdNONh-ptOordzDzej5n3XF_udf35zH2nd8dv6pSmA7dsbJyxnaZ-cAOfu8zmK7-PGac2iPPhJFnoQodLTVv49bgaS9noEYxCARmkHIa2rBCNCQcphOAQI8ApJw5202IkUJFoP4jVlEzKI_rp6NJkMqHAnAsFUWSWeoK3tKWp1gZTMfSSpu9a6vsLnrztov9bPw)

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 42 bytes

```
f(x,n)=x^{floor(n/2^{[0...ceil(log_2n)]})}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wsjsxxrck0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes (-1 @Steffan, -2 @dingledooper)

```
f=lambda x,n:[1][n:]or[x**n]+f(x,n/2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lY9NasMwEIX3PsUQKMiu4kryT2NDehGjhVrbRGBLQlJLcpZuvCk9S4-Q23ScpNkXhpnR9-bNoM9vd4oHa8SyfL3Hcbs7P4z7Sc2vvYIjNW3HZWdaaX13zDIjH0eC9Emkt-E3PTvrI4RTSEbrYdJmAG3Wdx5ir03uB9WvNJC0TUBTC3uYlSPDh5roKuTBTTqSDWxfYJOmCTivTSSajiTTKbW3U8v5BwAKCoJjXYc7zsqaFVUhGOKqYWWDaok9VsxcJpwxRoHB3SET7ARq1R8qxHO9QyAwYYiLDzVOoUQ3u_oo_C_WFQKb4n66ETWnF8bl9Ue_)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 40 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:[x**n]+(n*[n]and f(x,n//2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lY9BbsIwEEX3OcWIlZ0aGNtJSpDoMbqJvHCVWLUUbCsERM_STTbtXXoEbtMJUPaVRjNf788fy5_f6WN8j2Gavo6jW24uzO16u39rLZxF2DbnPA_miYW8CcaGFhwjvF4rzu_7ry4O0PvQgQ8QUxcY8tXQ2XZmB8a3GXgRYQd7m1h3sr2YjdUh9X5kC1i-wILzDNLgw8i8cCz3XMT79enyAwBagJI05-VGYlGhLrVCwmWNRU1uQZomdWkyiYgCEB4Jk5FS5JV_SKvnakNAUaNS1xx5UkBBabzlBPyv5hOKhH48XatKiiuT5vajXw)

Doesn't actually implement the algorithm. But produces correct output.

Comment: I guess you could save a byte if you wanted to use Python 2

Comment: True ...@Steffan

Comment: 38 bytes? `f=lambda x,n:[1][n:]or[x**n]+f(x,n//2)`

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 59 bytes

```java
x->n->{for(n*=2;n>0;)System.out.println(Math.pow(x,n/=2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY69TsMwFIVn8hQe7aoxEIkpxAtSpQ6dOiIG4zrBwb627OvSKsqzBwNhgrvd7@j8jPIs6/H0vhgXfEQylp9nNJb3GRQaD3zTVn/E/1jCqKX7kkJ@tUYRZWVK5CANkKki5RJKLHy3Jj/uAfWg45Y8eUjZ6fhLhCB9t1xqAbWYeh8pbLqmBXHXsuM1oXbcZ@QhGkAL9CDxjQf/QS9buO0axtp5ab8L1yFr79mbE3FlDj1isQ7PL0TGIbGpuum5DMFeacO4VEoHpPcP7CdjrublEw)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 16 bytes

```
⊣⋆{×?∾⌊÷2;0}
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=QmluRXhwIOKGkCDiiqPii4Z7w5fwnZWpP/CdlaniiL7wnZWK4oyK8J2VqcO3MjswfQozIEJpbkV4cCAyMQo=)

```
  {          }    # Recursive function acting on right argument  :
     ?            # if
   ×             # sign of  is non-zero
      ∾          # join  to
                 # the result(s) of a recursive call to this function
                  # with argument:
         ⌊        # floor of
          ÷2     #  divided by 2.
                  # Now, get
⊣                 # the left argument
 ⋆                # raised to these powers
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 45 bytes

```
_*0*[1].
X*N*[P|R]:-P is X^N,T is N//2,X*T*R.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P17LQCvaMFaPK0LLTys6oCYo1ko3QCGzWCEizk8nBMTw09c30onQCtEK0vtvr6tgpGVoquWoo1BQlJlXouGoqfcfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code, 24 bytes

Or 1 less for 32-bit mode, with 1-byte `dec ecx`.  If anyone has any other ideas for golfing further, please comment; I expect there's room for improvement.  A straightforward binary exponentiation that doesn't have to produce the exact same proof-of-"work" array output is only 19 bytes.

#### Actually implements a binary-exponentiation algorithm, not doing a separate `pow` for every output element.  Only one or two other answers do this, and I think this is the only iterative (non-recursive) one of those.

This is a function that takes an output pointer in RDI, to an array of DWORDs.  `x` in ESI, `n` in EBX.  (EDX is clobbered by `mul`.  This can be signed if you want; `mul` and `imul` are the same binary operation *on EAX*, differing only in the EDX high half.  They're the same size.)

Outputs: Array of steps in the memory the caller passed, RDI points to one-past-end.  EAX = `x**n`.

trimmed NASM listing: address, machine-code (the answer), source

```
                   expint: ; uint32_t *out (rdi),  x = esi   n = ebx
 00 6A01               push 1
 02 58                 pop  rax        ;    mov eax,1
 03 AB                 stosd           ;  *rdi++ = eax
 04 0FBDCB             bsr  ecx, ebx   ; bit-scan-reverse.  we need to loop bits high to low; a set bit cares about (gets squared by) how many bits are *below* it, not above.
                                ; ECX = bit-index of highest set bit
 07 740E               jz   .n0        ; exponent=0 is a special case
                   .loop:
 09 F7E0               mul  eax     ; square total
 0B 0FB3CB             btr  ebx, ecx          ; bit-test-reset.  Or just BT, clearing n as we go wasn't helpful.
 0E 7302               jnc .was_even
 10 F7E6                mul  esi     ; total *= x;   (destroys EDX with the high-half result, but this saves a byte vs. imul eax, esi)
                   .was_even:
 12 AB                 stosd
 13 FFC9               dec  ecx
 15 7DF2               jge .loop     ; }while(--bitpos >= 0);  // loop runs for ECX=0, can't use LOOP unless we left-shifted EBX or something
                   .n0:
 17 C3                 ret
                   
size: 0x18 = 24 bytes
```

It feels like there should be room to golf more, but it's tricky to cover the corner cases (like `n==0` is costing 2 bytes) and the off-by-ones (e.g. having to run the loop body for ECX=0 means I can't use `loop`).

Starting with `1` isn't as much of a burden as I'd thought it might be, mostly just requiring an extra `stosd` to output before the first multiply and after the last.  We need to start with the MSB, not LSB, so we always have a `1` bit so the first iteration can do `1*1 * x` to get us started with total=x.  That does let us fall into the loop with `total=1` after all.  If not for having to store the `n`, though, I'd likely start with EAX=`x` and adjust the loop somehow.

(The test-case I asked for with a non-trivial even power turned out not to be relevant for this; I hadn't realized you needed to start from the high end for an iterative version.  But it makes sense if you think about it: a `1` in the lowest bit of `n` results in a `*x` at the end.  But if you do that at the *start*, a bunch of squaring happens so that odd power becomes an even power.  If you just `shr ebx, 1` / `jnc` to divide by 2 and check for odd/even, you'd effectively be bit-reversing the exponent, or something like that.  Which works for exponents like `15` that have no significant zeros, but not others.)

**Update: you don't have to start from the MSB, I just had a brain fart**: the normal algorithm would do `x *= x;` every iteration, only multiplying it into the total for set bits in `n`. The algorithm is identical to multiplication by shifting-and-adding, in case it helps to think about how adding partial products works. ([Stepanov's lectures on algorithms](https://youtu.be/PtGVOGui7q4?t=230) uses binary exponentiation as one of the main examples, pointing out that replacing `+` with `*` makes exponentiation instead of multiplication.)  This question's presentation in terms of square-rooting the total in reverse got me stuck on squaring the total instead of x, and if you do that then you have to go from MSB downward.

No CPU I'm aware of has an integer sqrt instruction, or a single-instruction `pow` to give a starting point.  (x87 has some exponential stuff, but takes multiple instructions to do pow.  Still maybe worth considering.

Hopefully we can still recover all the same intermediate values this question wants, while doing `shr ecx,1` / `jnc`.  But that would make starting with `1` inconvenient.

---

BMI2 `mulx` is a 5-byte instruction, so even if we could reuse FLAGS to save a dec or test, it wouldn't pay for itself.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVXBjuJGEL37K15OmWGAwbC7kQaRSLMzySXKrpIcRooi1LYLbNJ0O@42mEj59tmqbsCQ1UrJKZYAu1xd9epV1UM5R9tMH0ZGue3rK3V1ZfwD5mj5dzZdegxs63HTFNXtEOiwALkKgJG7rEv4FnXrSqTx1tZAozocr7l8be0OpLphdHHeugL9xS4DDn93JxFVjJi5BqC8G0qO4LMnGKIC3kJbTpJV3qGs1mW07OdQcOTFjlw15KCygHxN7Oj@bNlWIDvcorR7bJU5xBBsxiAjjjBA5Ycw1svJHY0TfHbN8fz@hWHyyVFlCupgVwEEOX/KHo5t/uKvsZn0B5lZa8j4xQSVE6w15ZXSjNVRMpaSHsLJbashNByPReBco1c6MuOFmUyYybtrbLbBpmUgj78OkWtSTWXW3CflhLy1xV4587VHSbpetTrWtzE5xvxiSTsyseKIIDRZoobUGCzQSS9vCi61sQeH56cX7CvP/JcUOBiVSq/AzLeaecyYe19yqU7tpBlMvSfs3BiVJJBxkCS3yTn7Qz8d4a6gPMxAxLkmBJaOqP7el5Wmm9GIGa@tw7cLTG4Z4P19HI@mNQ4rZoQbtpgwH0pKbx3hxw8fPqI1mlzgRdPKj1xZrTyPx/Pji7Do7JYYu1kn3MIIqyH/OmcypNG50pqaMfBkKTBaM9MePG11y5U7Pqhp5DzVPFGoDH54ekwSpau1QfouWWubMaNL51Xjk/hzrL3N0Lh6iDeTSXJaHF6NoViTfpUcW9IJ@/QmWZX@TPCY9o8yLunb8CzgEdc8@TzHVYDZdYBpGqdsR82K18WdJaKHcUp8YQip3/3X1Ok317kvSguVdul09ubtefJDW5y2dX3A4y8/c1PVToZfRYXgAal8taM4Grltjf8yIJnM6ewoVQcnPkmSRK/lLl1mjf2Dh/XfSuRxfv@hg/ML2Zxf6mZ8smf1O1k22/piT4OJi4xOvzV5d8cf3CH9/aoOAXLeJYEy71fsqDnz66ULy998WX5ceYKWynuD@wWmXPX777lYqwuR4l4Fr8WF9yckXbIMNoeHC@USvVtwxEFgbjweQ5lCUDX0HfCTrWl4Vv9gPf7bRLT/v1SF@YsNO@mV4X@AUG1kuDJHMYutkzns5Uywb3Ajgv6V6FgwzaaibdzKguC2QXJOSpS8fgI) with `_start` test caller (doesn't print: use GDB `display *(int[8]*)($rsp+8)` to display the output array state as you single-step, given that the caller passes RDI=RSP as the output.)

#### 19 bytes, different array from a more normal algorithm:

```
expint_v2: ; uint32_t *out (rdi),  x = esi   n = ebx
    push 1
    pop  rax      ; mov eax,1
    stosd
.loop:              ;do{
    shr  ebx, 1  ; n /= 2,  CF = old low bit
    jnc .was_even
    mul  esi          ; total *= x;   (destroys EDX with the high-half result, but this saves a byte vs. imul eax, esi)
.was_even:
    stosd             ; *out++ = eax
    imul esi, esi     ; square x
    test ebx, ebx
    jnz  .loop      ;}while(n!=0);
    ret
```

Same inputs as before, same result in EAX and the highest array element (since the last bit shifted out before it becomes zero is a `1`, unless `n=0` in which case we leave the loop without having done `mul esi`.)

e.g. for 3^21 it produces these steps, where `1870418611` is 3^21 mod 2^32.

```
{1, 3, 3, 243, 243, 1870418611}
```

The `x*=x` steps where `n` doesn't have a set bit don't change the running product.  (Like for multiply by addition, where you're not adding a partial product at that shift.)

I don't think it's possible to recover the same proof-of-work temporaries from this (even with a `mov`/`imul` into another temp), because we're working from the low bit up, not from the high bit down.

Starting with `1` is actually helpful, since we actually need to *not* start with `total = x` if `n` is even, but after we square x this iteration we no longer have any odd power of the original `x` left to multiply by, so the total would remain an odd power.

Starting with `total=1` also makes the n=0 case Just Work for free.

Anyway, this order of temporaries is perhaps less interesting, but could probably also be recovered from a recursive implementation.  I'm curious whether another challenge, perhaps titled iterative binary exponentiation, would get different answers in other languages.  Probably still easier to use `**` or `^` built-ins in languages that have them, after generating the right array of what, prefix-sum of bit-indices of non-zero bits or something?

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＩＸθＥ⊕Ｌ↨η²↨²✂↨η²¦⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyC/PLVIo1BHwTexQMMzL7koNTc1ryQ1RcMnNS@9JEPDKbE4VSNDR8FIU1NTRwHMM9JRCM7JTE5FktNRMNBRyNQEA@v//6ONgYKGsf91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the list in ascending order (+1 byte to output in the order given in the question). Explanation:

```
  θ                 First input `x`
 Ｘ                  Vectorised raised to power
       η            Second input `n`
      ↨ ²           Converted to base 2
     Ｌ              Take the length
    ⊕               Incremented
   Ｅ                Map over implicit range
             η      Second input `n`
            ↨ ²     Converted to base 2
           ✂    ⁰   Sliced to length
                 ι  Current value
         ↨²         Converted from base 2
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Although Charcoal's `BaseString()` function would convert `0` to `"0"`, its `Base()` function returns an array rather than a string, and this array is empty when `n=0`, so it doesn't have the problem that, say, the 05AB1E answer has. Instead, it has the problem that `CycleChop([], 0)` throws a `ZeroDivisionError`, so I have to use `Slice()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 69 bytes

```
^
1,
\d+$
*
+`(.+),(.+),\b(_*)\3(_?)
$1¶$.($($.4*$2,1)***),$2,$3
,.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsNADAT7fYcCkk4cJ59Tu8wnjtgJSZHGhfHb/AB/7CzSDDuwzPbdf@vL@40fS3/CDe2TCIq0cE5if7Q3zyqt8jwJyM@DMhNTHpUGc1FVsVhUYTmhE86jVxscXkqxgjjdIz2GhbjVCw) Link includes test cases. Outputs the list in ascending order. Explanation:

```
^
1,
```

Prefix a `1` which is the working value for the result.

```
\d+$
*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
(.+),(.+),\b(_*)\3(_?)
```

Match the previous result, `x`, `n/2` and `n%2`.

```
$1¶$.($($.4*$2,1)***),$2,$3
```

Keep a copy of the previous result, then square it and multiply it by `x` or `1` depending on whether `n` was odd. (Retina only uses the first integer it finds in a string, so multiplying `3,1`, `59049,3,_` and `59049,3,_` is equivalent to multiplying `3`, `59049` and `59049`.) Append `x` and `n/2` for the next pass through the loop.

```
+`
```

Repeat the above until `n=0`.

```
,.+
```

Delete `x`.

Retina doesn't have exponentiation. Retina 1 does however have both eval and multiplication, so exponentiation can be (slowly) performed in 30 bytes:

```
~`(.+),(.+)
.+¶$$.($2*$($1$*)_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8L8uQUNPW1MHRHDpaR/apqKip6FipKWioWKooqUZ//@/sY6RIZehgYGBjgGXkY6hKZehjgmQB@QY6hgDAA) Link includes examples.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
M^U¡÷2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zcu9NDCw9uN/v//b2Tw3xgA)

Another port of [Steffan's answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249464/95126): upvote those.

```
   ¡      # Apply function repeatedly, collect values in infinite list:
          #  (using arg1 as starting value)
    ÷2    #  Integer-divide by 2
  U       # Longest prefix with all unique elements
M         # Map over this:
 ^        #  arg2 to the power of this
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 20 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍵=0:1⋄(⍺*⍵),⍺∇⌊⍵÷2}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu9XWwMrwUXeLxqPeXVpArqYOkPGoo/1RTxeQd3i7US0A&f=M1JIUzA0BQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

-2 bytes thanks to Vadim Tukaev

Comment: Excellent brainchild! You can save two bytes: {⍵=0:1⋄(⍺*⍵),⍺∇⌊⍵÷2}