# Implement pow with overflow checking

Tags: code-golf, math

Implement a function or program which raises `x` to the power of `y`. Inputs are 16-bit signed integers. That is, both are in the range [-32768, 32767]. The output should be in the same range. I chose this range because it should make it possible to do exhaustive testing to ensure all edge-cases are covered.

If the output can't be represented (it's too negative, too positive or not an integer), do one of the following:

- Throw an exception
- Print an error message
- Return a special value (-1, 0 or any other specific value)

Please document what your implementation does in case of error; the behavior should be identical for all error cases — the same exception, message or exceptional value!

By definition, 0 to the power of 0 is 1 (not "error").

I am most interested in non-trivial solutions, but if your language has a suitable `pow` function, you are allowed to use it!

Test cases:

```
pow(-32768, -32768) = error
pow(-32768, -1) = error
pow(-32768, 0) = 1
pow(-32768, 1) = -32768
pow(-32768, 2) = error
pow(-32768, 32767) = error
pow(-100, 100) = error
pow(-180, 2) = 32400
pow(-8, 5) = -32768
pow(-3, -2) = error
pow(-3, 9) = -19683
pow(-2, 15) = -32768
pow(-1, -999) = -1
pow(-1, -100) = 1
pow(-1, 100) = 1
pow(-1, 999) = -1
pow(0, -100) = error
pow(0, -1) = error
pow(0, 0) = 1
pow(0, 999) = 0
pow(1, -999) = 1
pow(1, 10000) = 1
pow(1, 9999) = 1
pow(2, 14) = 16384
pow(2, 15) = error
pow(8, 5) = error
pow(4, 7) = 16384
pow(181, 2) = 32761
pow(182, 2) = error
pow(10000, 1) = 10000
```

Comment: Can `-1` and `0` really be used as the special value? They are indistinguishable from a valid answer.

Comment: It's too bad, but you don't have any other choice if all your language has is 16-bit integers.

Comment: If the code throws an exception to indicate error, does it have to be the same exception in every case? For instance, `pow(-32768, -32768)` is defined but not an integer whereas `pow(0, -1)` is undefined (division by zero).

Comment: It should be the same. Updated the text.

Answer (score 14):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 68 bytes

```
|x:i16,y:i16|x.checked_pow(match x{1|-1=>y&1,_=>y}.try_into().ok()?)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZJLTsMwEIYlljnF0AWyJaey05IHVWHDmg3Lqoqq1lGj0gRSVyS0PQmbLuACcAtuAKfBseM2SSELOzOe-eb3eF7fsvVKfIw6ts1nsYjTZOhQh3XGn1ECy0mcIAwbeOACIhi-r0Vk-9-32_wqZi4pynWbd6dzPl3wWfiYPqPlREznkG_Y1mbD6-KCkVBuu67IijBORIpwN10gfIM16-fsa2BFaQYoJ1AQeMEQJzCyQH7I7jme65eVoPZ7lyYcE3Mqj9ipjxK4T5ccMZmBManjCLDqUNu4nuecosrNM-4KxKgsoJZDNPOpSlfkntOnVIMl4bJdz8iR2hsFCQQmlAWu39MEGcL-Q8ir2EFwzNIZpVep0z04OP_ytbI1lxqA0Uabbaa1DuPKcQTRA6cpT4dqHS0lWkgjUBPKy_eN2-35fRVetcTI0T02lgz3WhmVGp_Vn8hzq9q-03j4Sp2ZEmVibI1hozCT1YpnIuRP5yhSQ4vLqR1YO2unR3q_1_sv)

Probably not the best language to golf in, but when I saw the description I immediately thought that `checked_pow` would be a perfect built-in for this task. The equivalent doesn't exist in every single other language I know of.

Returns `Some(x**y)` if the result is well-defined and fits in the `i16` range, `None` otherwise.

```
|x:i16,y:i16|           A closure that takes two i16 values
x.checked_pow(...)      Raise x to the power of ... (but the power must be u32)
                        The only cases where negative power makes sense are 1 and -1
match x{                so let's match on x and
1|-1=>y&1,              if it is 1 or -1, use y modulo 2 (non-negative)
_=>y}                   and simply use y otherwise
.try_into()             and try converting to u32 (inferred)
.ok()                   and convert the Result<u32,E> to Option<u32>
?                       and return None immediately if the conversion fails
```

Comment: Re: other languages with overflow-detecting operations: GNU C has `__builtin_mul_overflow` - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html.  But not `pow`; yeah that's a rare one.  Using signed integer, `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` will abort the program on signed-overflow UB if you just use plain `*=`, but that doesn't help either for *returning* an error to the caller.

Comment: Using release flags and by moving a type annotation you can get 59 bytes: `|x:i16,y|x.checked_pow(if 0i16>y&&x*x!=1{None?}else{y}as _)`

Comment: @AnttiP That would panic if `x*x` overflows.

Comment: @L.F. Not with release flags, it will simply overflow. [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY9BTsMwEEXX-BTTLCq7cmgcpLYiCtwAFrCrqihKxsJqY0PiioQ0J2HTBZyADVfpGbgESdNKkTqbmflf80b_8yvfFvZ36bgupsoqo0Pf84XDwXEfndWP1JDFSlMGNWzQgoTwe2uluzgEu_JWiRmvduV18oLJGtPo1bxTJcFr9btqPC4n5SgU9YPReN_gpsC6auICInZC_AVEmhxoyaHi8MFAaVgSaIu6N_58tuj4MBg7EuNnt7XEpeZxeDIZUtFeMMaHOA7iZPY7G975l6iuzc8yuZpO4TlXWYYpWANSWUhMu2lLVlAf_8RFgbmN8G1E5TEV62IFpCFNH3m_7_s_)

Comment: @AnttiP Indeed, forgot about that!

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>46</s>  41 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

Expects `(x)(y)`. Returns `false` for errors.

```javascript
x=>y=>(q=x**y/(y>=0|x*x<2))==q<<16>>16&&q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZRfa4MwFMXf9yl8KonQeW/UGMHku5TOjo1Spx1DYd/dJUoh5k@dL4Hw45yccxM/Tz@n@3n4@Po@3rq3dr7IeZRqkor0ckzTKSOTkvA7pmPDKJWybxrkSiE/HPr53N3u3bV9vXbv5EKOOau4oI@VJkmWJe0wdMNLBEQDmW8HhAdnQIxAaEPrZoRkNvnM1yzVAsdABNDOALuKKMA2XsCcFQAuqG1LC3uWRjdoK8bTUFJ7klhzkbsk02FKRzJsjtq8ri3ZRTNE2e0E54fbBqPQxi7oB65drBKwL98OCBsudDhwz2Ygd7BeYSGltYqdwtYqdpTMJAs3IfJcFAGw/E8V3sWMgQUlld9ZwBoFbt/E@igq7iUWzAdD1mt51q9gsTab8x8)

#### Commented

```javascript
x =>            // given x
y =>            // and y
(               //
  q =           // compute and save in q:
    x ** y /    //   x ** y
    (           //   leave it unchanged if:
      y >= 0 |  //     y is non-negative
      x * x < 2 //     or x² is 0 or 1
    )           //   otherwise: divide by 0, leading to +/- Infinity
) ==            // test whether the result is invariant by shifting it ...
q << 16 >> 16   // ... by 16 positions to the left and then to the right
&& q            // if it is: return q (or return false otherwise)
```

Comment: Does `x=>y=>(q=x**y/(y>=0|x*x<2))==(q<<16>>16)&&q` work or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Yes, I've overlooked that bit shifts have higher precedence.

Comment: @Neil I can't think of any case where it would not work. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>30</s></sup> 29 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{[x**=y][x>>15]rescue p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBDoMgELz3FZwbbHapVjnoRwiH1mh6NDYmGvXtdM0iwonZ3ZlhB8bps7i@dlkzy2U18/1eL9bMTYOFHbtfO3Vi2J25CZM9VfmqpODTyriFSQlJlc5UUh1HyR0EIC54LVYQuMQrvIquUgFqRopkfo4011pfxeUXe5PUkyDiQMgBZwS4mLE1m3kZu/HgWCUPiJcK2@dScFSs8MyGlQrwcOTXso/u3X7FutGXbGIQvSFgd/cH)

Returns `nil` for errors.

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVExDoMwDNz7ilTqhADZKRQY4CNRBopAHTpUICQQ8HZq5BCSKXf23cVO@vE97125R9UUzgsGagqCctZqqipM9barm1DRU2avPBR86tAtoUfBY35Peuw4Mq4gAGnBeDEHqyVdalx0lbSwYCTJZvpI/aIoLnLludlkNSJwNGD3gHMFuJRuNIcZG6dx4xglsYiHstMnoeBVMcdzN8ylhUciv5aO27r5iGWlz1jFT3SKgBZ9OzRjS/xxj5tvPQzb/gc "Ruby – Try It Online") if different errors are allowed to throw different exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 36 bytes

```
f(x,y)=iferr([z=x^y,z][2+z>>15],t,e)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFLDoIwEI03aYgLiCWZVpGykIsQNI0RQ0JMQ9AAV3HjxngmPY1th2Jd9c3Me28-vb-UbOvDWT0ez2tXxeK9rMKeDtGurk5tGxbjrt8PdCwLvhrznCUl7egpQu5ncZNKNUMoSZwT1daXTsPABAE5yqYJK0pkFFFSFPGap1tBCb6lTs0Z5kfgB38V7gfmSW2CAWgioI4JcERNSlChW3CHMgu4VmCR6WKWZTOejTxPrUIG_Ajg5oZpZJhZniW6oAJtbNq03zhg53DDbiixWzHBpj2Y4A4ZJ3OTcjq_-7Iv)

A port of [Dingus's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249693/9288). Returns `e` for errors.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFLCsIwEMWbBFctpjCJn6aL9iKlShArhSKhKNhuPYabbsQzeBVP4yRjaoTAvJl5780kuT-N7prd0Yzj43KuE_Wqoyvv47wc8uu250NVysVQFGJdUf89u2lj2j7SLCmY6ZrTGeHcJnPW1Ieui_a6baOaMx1zdsATYyzLZCnTjeKMYoWlqSLCDMLkryPDxIbUFQQAEoF0QoEnImlNChwhPcockKigpsBmlmUTnowCT1QRA34E8HvDd2WYWIEluZCCbFzZjl954Pbwy644c7cSSnzvIZT0yDrZN6li-gv_Zx8) if different errors are allowed to print different messages.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:int([x**n][x*x>1and x**n>>15])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPLjoMgFF3LVxA3SgcnoNZHE/sjrQtaNWNi1aAzY6fptzuAVmvtBriHe849XKC@tl9V6fR19Rsd@4JdTgmDHS53edmah26zKWMxdnvKygTKcL@n2xj1bdq0DYygYRhAcE3LsX0vwHCYkdhJOa/4co@@x4mE6QJSmUOwwO33CnLyX7YoIUKHkFc4IKOMY7uEDKCQ2K4qCsOrchiGKo@GXuAMmC2qrMhUkMNwzJ2h0c6MrIAlicyc2QVZd5IsmkgmmeF4T2boAxCqz6WHyk8p8lSuCj0ncCdou6z76NuMuBj6SxoN6NRw3xvLBfbqLpWj8ebVGsi3BfJLXfEW8hT8sOI7lW@Op59ZXiasKExDMI@meSBWaMUfCMNpeZQ6KmLWnwQMDNWjRQBkFYcMn/AZ5iUcZHdAa/lVjFoieE3LTelJfgImVOV8QggBLe3Oad0@8nRlXwdAq7n6MHrG8kLHes2aRo8P5yhKYgwzXYrd2B3D2@kujd2Su45A/w8)

TIO link using codes from movatica's answer.

This function throw errors when failed. But different errors for different testcases.

Code `lambda x,n:[x**n][x**n>>15]` failed when \$\lvert x\rvert=1 \land n<0\$.

Comment: `x**n>>15` will be 0 if x is an integer in 0~32767, or -1 if `x**n` is an integer in `-32768~-1`, or raise exception is `x**n` is non-integer, or other integer values for other cases (which try to access array `[x**n]` out of range and raise another exception).

Comment: Nice solution with the shifting test!

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>86</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
k=32768
g(n)=\{-k<=n<k\}\{\mod(n,1)=0\}
f(a,b)=g(a)g(a^b)g(b)a^b\{b>=0,aa=1\}
```

Returns `undefined` for errors. Not sure if this is fully correct, but it at least passes all the test cases.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vctyq9udgb)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yi1teei5an)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 114 bytes

```
^(-?1,)-
$1
/,-/(K`
T`-`_`.+[02468]$
~`-?(.+),(.+)
\d.+¶$$.($2*$($1$*)_
A`\d{6}
\d+
*_#
A`^(-_)?_{32768}
(_*)#
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU0xUgMxDOz1jZgZ@05yLOdysasbKgpaOgI2M6FIQ8HQZcKzeAAfOyRfjkLSarW7@nz/On@88XxnH@r8amlidASGYYu0tY8VnirVUn3/HOIwphcD35Um63uH2uB48v3vjzHemtgZa9h0rsB9PZ4u41WuPXRlI7tEFzeVyy4exnQFWzq3AeN5nqlR2AasC68orOCfiStYDBwCSglIQW8J9yJAUhlmoIgsBCPlnNtcxDcPKhsWUoc0BcreLE0p1ybNIHEDtEx9NOABOLH85RS1qxT5Dw) Link includes test cases modified to run in a reasonable amount of time on TIO. Outputs nothing in case of error. Explanation:

```
^(-?1,)-
$1
```

Negating the exponent of `1` or `-1` has no effect.

```
/,-/(K`
```

Other negative exponents are an error, otherwise:

```
T`-`_`.+[02468]$
```

Even exponents always produce a non-negative result.

```
~`-?(.+),(.+)
\d.+¶$$.($2*$($1$*)_
```

Perform the exponentiation by evaluation of repeated multiplication of `1` by the base.

```
A`\d{6}
```

Values of six or more digits are an error.

```
\d+
*_#
```

Convert to unary, with a marker to make it golfier to convert negative numbers back to decimal. (Conveniently it also makes it possible to distinguish between `0` and error.)

```
A`^(-_)?_{32768}
```

Values of `32768` or `-32769` or greater absolute value are an error.

```
(_*)#
$.1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```c
f(a,b){float c=pow(a,b);a=c-(short)c?0:c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJBboMwEEXX4RQjdQMSVGMgYEJpz@K6kCARqLCjLqJcvdTg0oRgNytLfn/@/PGYB3vOh6e65c3po4QXJkTZy@fD61C5zH/3zlXTMQm8@Oy@poucFTxwxaHrpcffcMfzy1C3Eo6sbl0Pzs5GSCZrDrxrhYQRlX3f9VAA5s5G@7uVG0RhmlAf9OlBUWidZxSRBwKcODEyXfvbxyQIH5iPR2rTEETVAtHKKc4dojBWugVV7lt7PDW4PZsPma4kWUKjJQxVJLsvUb5ZNlev2TzNGtmJxQ9v7NZD4D@bRfNS8dpq@ZS3Q5F7oiIYk@vgpqLxBWN9n0Q0XrGtJfbfQtco9iG1OBJKrp8kTe5C0tD@R6fJ5j@ux8wd5zJ886phezEEzfEH)

1 byte shaved off thanks to ceilingcat.

Uses the standard library's [`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow), which works on `double`s, which themselves might overflow but will then become ±infinity, and then checking if the result is representable as a `short`.

Comment: Abusing the ambiguity in return value, great!

Comment: Huh, this doesn't actually detect the underflow in `32767 ^ -32768 ~= 2^-491518.55` (way below FLT_MIN), but returning `c` means returning `0`.  Good approach to handle / sidestep the seemingly-pointless requirement to handle negative exponents for an integer power function, in languages where you have an easy to access FP pow available.  (Unlike assembly, for example.)

Comment: @PeterCordes x86 can calculate *approximate* float and integer pow with log2 instructions and bsr.

Comment: @xiver77: I considered looking into an x87 FP `pow` function with `frint` or `fistp` at the end, but for an integer problem was more interested in golfing an integer implementation (to take advantage of `imul`'s built-in detection of signed overflow out of that range; see my answer).  Pretty sure an x87 pow would be *at least* as long, and obviously `bsr` is way too approximate; rounding up or down to a power of 2 is huge error when we need an exact integer result.

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, 12 bytes

Could save 1 byte by using opcode `CE` ([`into`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1)) to trap on OF=1, instead of jumping to return from the function.

- 32-bit mode: 13 bytes: need a 66 operand-size prefix for `imul si`, rest can use the same machine code bytes, which will give 32-bit operand-size.  (So in source you'd write it as `xor eax,eax`/`inc eax`.  And `jecxz`.  `loop` automatically uses the address-size as the width of CX/ECX/RCX it uses, so the mode-sized width of that register is significant as an arg.)
- 64-bit mode, 14 bytes: like 32-bit plus `inc eax` is a 2-byte instruction.  (Negative exponents will run nearly 2^64 iterations, so rather impractical, unlike 32-bit bit mode where it only takes a couple seconds when the base is `-1` so it doesn't overflow.)

**Fixme: non-competing, doesn't handle `pow(0, -100) = error`, instead returns 0**.  Handles any non-zero base with any exponent, or any base with any non-negative exponent.  I don't see why it's interesting to have an integer power function allow negative exponents in the first place; unsigned or guaranteed non-negative would make more sense.  But I think this is interesting because `0 ** (unsigned)n` with overflow-checked multiply comes
so close to handling everything without any special work to deal with negative exponents.

NASM listing: address, machine-code (the answer proper), source

```
                    checked_pow:      ; x in SI,  n in (ER)CX
 00 31C0               xor  ax,ax
 02 40                 inc  ax      ; mov [e]ax,1  and clear OF
 03 E306               jcxz  .exit
                   .loop:              ;do{
 05 F7EE               imul  si         ; total *= x;
 07 7002               jo  .exit        ; break on signed overflow of the low half (i.e. if cwd would change DX)
 09 E2FA               loop .loop      ;}while(--n!=0);
                   .exit:
 0B C3                 ret
```

Function taking args in SI and CX, returning an out-of-band error status in OF (the overflow flag), and a value in AX.  **The AX value is meaningful if OF=0, otherwise there was overflow.**  (So just like an instruction like `add`; the caller can `into` to trap on overflow if they want, or `jo` like this function did.)

Widening multiply can't actually lose any bits, so x86's `mul` and [`imul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) instructions set FLAGS according to whether the low half is the same as the full result.  i.e. whether the high half is the zero- or sign-extension of the low half respectively.  i.e. after `imul`, if `cwd` to sign-extend AX into DX:AX would change anything.  If the result doesn't fit in the low half, CF=OF=1, otherwise they're cleared to zero.

Corner case handling:

- `x^0` (including 0^0) correctly returns 1, detected with `jcxz`.  If not for this, could save 2 bytes
- `x^negative` correctly overflows for `|x| > 1`, because **`loop` treats the count as unsigned**.  Any negative exponent is treated as an unsigned exponent of at least 32768 (in 16-bit mode; much higher in 32 or 64-bit mode if sign-extended into ECX or RCX as required, instead of zero-extended to be large positive).

  Any base other than 1, 0, or -1 will result in signed overflow in at most 16 iterations.
- `-1^negative` correctly returns 1 or -1, according to the exponent being odd or even.  Negative even two's complement signed integers have their low bit clear, so represent even unsigned numbers.  To put it another way, `-1^-n = -1^|n|`, and 2's complement absolute value doesn't change the low bit.
- `0^negative`: **unhandled**, we just do `0 ** (unsigned)n`, producing zero without overflowing like we should for 1/0.

---

Semi-related: [Implement Binary Exponentiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249463/implement-binary-exponentiation/249723#249723) shows a more efficient algorithm (more bytes, but much faster for large `n`.  Of course overflow happens so fast that it's not a big deal except for degenerate cases like `1` and `-1` with huge exponents.  Since we don't need performance here, it's of course smaller code to just use the O(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 73 bytes

```c
c;f(a,b){c=b?b>0||!(a+1&~2)&&(b=-b)?a*f(a,b-1):0:1;return(short)c-c?0:c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLtcoIwEPzPU1zt6CQUOpdoKx9FHqEv0D8QRJmx0IHYqaP20UsTGTDwa7OX3b3cgXB3QrSPRSkOx2wLb43Miup5v7GsRiayEK0Ic5I4KT2LKI3TDV4uDyR5YotfThcLkkZuSuPEvmlcRgMMWFhv5bEuSbOvakmFK2IMRHhtv6siA0mKUsKPAxpOFM4WwFetSE5mZJ5RsG24YQTz7KOcOVp7ciAnGikNratlae9nUpSk80viLvn61XOgQyUaFdmkgBM@vecTrmHd1xiicuCQwTw0HEr9MrhVa24Qvz9zFTComFL5vm9SM33cS4UMUhwp0ZgT7yOi6Ri36qKHgC67v9RPXBnn/rnGfCsH@qUwj913wDxuEN2h33D3XwCqb9j@ifyQ7JrWfV/@Aw)

(-1 bytes @ceilingcat)
(-5 bytes @JuanIgnacioDíaz)

Returns `0` for error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
ＮθＮη¿∨⁼¹↔θ¬‹η⁰ＩΦ⟦Ｘθ↔η⟧№…±Ｘ⁸¦⁵Ｘ⁸¦⁵ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYw/C8IwEEf3foobLxBBh0KhkxQFQWJxFYe0xCYQE5s/@vHjFZd62@Pe741ahtFLW8rJvXIS@TmogDNrqzVrYvMAvAQ8zFnaiDsO@yF6m5Mim3EQPuFZxYiaw5bRQR@MS9jJmPBobKLMrfefpb7aasbuHDqfSb1KNykUapL0@KkNh3qp/5NZ@m0pTVWXzdt@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs nothing in case of error. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `x` and `y`.

```
¿∨⁼¹↔θ¬‹η⁰
```

If the absolute value of `x` is `1` or `y` is non-negative, then:

```
ＩΦ⟦Ｘθ↔η⟧№…±Ｘ⁸¦⁵Ｘ⁸¦⁵ι
```

Output `x` to the power of `y` if it lies in the range `[-32768,32768)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
S&€hṡ32768^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1jtUdOajIc7FxobmZtZxP3//9/ov66hhQEA) or [try some of the test-cases](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/cGfjw11dj5oa/werPWpak/Fw50JjI3Mzi7j///9HR@uC2ToQKlYnWtcQwTZAMJFEjRBMEG2OpMgAqANIQBQZWhiAzTCAmGoQGwsA)

Outputs `0` as 'special value' for error.

```
          ^    # pow without overflow/error checking;
    ṡ32768     # range from -32768 to 32768
   h           # without the last element
               # (so: -32768 to 32767);
  €            # is the pow a member of this range?
S&             # if yes, output the pow
               # if no, output falsy = zero
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 52 B

The ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” defines the integer power operator `pow`.
NB: [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) causes an error.
Provided that the implementation-defined value of the required constant `maxInt` is greater than or equal to `32768` you can wrap `pow` into a function like this:

```pascal
function f(x,y:integer):integer;begin f:=x pow y end
```

The standard specifies that

> It shall be an error if an integer operation or function is not performed according to the mathematical rules for integer arithmetic.

An *error* is

> A violation by a program of the requirements of this International Standard that a processor is permitted to leave undetected.

Thus *whether* and *how* an overflow is signaled is at the compiler developer’s discretion.